# Encode abstract classes into json with dart

Tags: json, dart

I want to serialize an List of abstract "AnimationDecorationInstances" types into json.
The purpose is to define a set of animations which are shown on the screen. The animationDecorations List shall contain all the animations. But the animations can be of different types with different attributes. The AnimationDecorationType is used to determine, which type of class is serialized into the List of animationDecorations.

So animationDecoration may consist of [text, text, filter, text, text, ...].

The code is the following:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'animation_decoration.g.dart';

@JsonEnum()
enum AnimationDecorationType { text, filter }

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
abstract class AnimationDecorationInstance {
  get getArtifactDecorationType;
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AnimationDecoration {
  List<AnimationDecorationInstance> animationDecorations = [];

  AnimationDecoration();

  factory AnimationDecoration.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AnimationDecorationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AnimationDecorationToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class TextEffect with AnimationDecorationInstance {
  final AnimationDecorationType animation_decoration_type =
      AnimationDecorationType.text;

  @override
  get getArtifactDecorationType => animation_decoration_type;

  double fromMillis = 0, toMillis = 0;

  String text = "";

  TextEffect();

  factory TextEffect.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$TextEffectFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TextEffectToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class FilterEffect with AnimationDecorationInstance {
  final AnimationDecorationType animation_decoration_type =
      AnimationDecorationType.filter;

  @override
  get getArtifactDecorationType => animation_decoration_type;

  int colorFilterAdaper = 0;


  FilterEffect();

  factory FilterEffect.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FilterEffectFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FilterEffectToJson(this);

}
```

Unfortunately I fail to generate the json classes because I get the error:

```
2022-07-24 12:54:23 Could not generate `fromJson` code for `animationDecorations` because of type `AnimationDecorationInstance`.
2022-07-24 12:54:23 package:sdg4/dto/animation_decoration.dart:14:37
2022-07-24 12:54:23    ╷
2022-07-24 12:54:23 14 │   List<AnimationDecorationInstance> animationDecorations = [];
2022-07-24 12:54:23    │                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2022-07-24 12:54:23    ╵
```

What is the right way to serialize "abstract" classes into json?

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote: "The AnimationDecorationType is used to determine, which type of class is serialized into the List of animationDecorations."  Used by you to determine? But how can this affect the software that knows nothing about it?

Comment: Yes, the software reads the List<AnimationDecorationInstance> from JSON and then queries the key "animation_decoration_type" of each json list entry. Depending on the value it knows that it now can query the key "colorFilterAdapter" or "fromMillis, toMillis, text" on the same list entry.